# Asp.net MVC type double modelbinder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, which uses the Entity Framework.
I have a simple database that contains a field of type float, which the entity framework automatically maps to the type double.

In a simple form of editing I try to update the value of this field, with a decimal value.i.e:
"3.45",or "121.34"

But the MVC always returns a validation error saying that these values ​​are not valid for type double.If I change these values to:"3"and "121",it works....

"3.45" and "121.34" are not valid values ​​for type double?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "3.45" and "121.34" are not valid values ​​for type double?

This will depend on the culture you are using and whether `.` is a valid decimal separator in this culture. This can be set in the [globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) element in web.config:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

If you leave it to `auto` the server will use the same culture as the client browser.

Comment: thank you man...but why I have to manually set this value in web.config, this should not come configured by default?

Comment: @ozsenegal, yes it comes configured by default. IIRC the default value is auto meaning that this will depend on your browser settings.